# How can I change resource dictionary styles dynamically using Theme values from a web service?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-store-apps

How can I change resource dictionary styles dynamically using Theme values from a web service?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Did you try anything so far?

Comment: not yet because I'm still waiting for a reply so that i can continue working ,I'm stuck and no clue where to go ,I'm still new in programming and windows store apps

Comment: Look up MergedDictionaries and go from there.

Comment: i did just that but i think what i need is a value converter that converts my theme class which has backgroundColor,image and font and pass it inside a resource dictionary so i can use it.